# Google Compute Engine - europe-west1-a has been offline for maintenance since Jan 18, 2014 9:00:00 PM

Tags: google-compute-engine

we don't recognized that our Servers will go down and stay down for the hole time.
because the instances were configured to migrate, if a maintenance will start, but this haven't be done.

Which options we have, to get the data or the instances back running, without waiting for the end of the maintenance on the 2th of february?

I hope someone have a solution for us, because we need the system back online.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this sounds like a support request for Google, not a question about code.

Comment: We have the same problem. The problem is we didn’t receive any email which informs us about the maintenance time. We can’t contact the support because we only got bronze support level, so no phone or mail support. I've never come across such an action with other server hosters. My decision is certain: Never use one of Google Hosting Products again.

Comment: Google has now put the zone back online until 19:00 US/Pacific Sun 19 Jan.

Comment: Zone is offline as before. Also yesterday (19 Jan) the zone was offline, i know it because i setup new server in the afternoon/evening and looked in the developers console very often. Why they dont send notifications when they are put the zone online again, is it to difficult for google to send emails?

Comment: 19:00 PST on Sunday is 05:00 AM Monday in Germany and that without notification. Thanks Google for offering such an awfully bad support.