# How to migrate old Google Compute Engine disks?

Tags: linux, mount, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Compute Engine in Europe and the maintenance window just [hit us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211011). The "automatic migration" didn't work, so all of our servers are offline. During the recovery from backup, we found a few files missing.

I have a persistent boot disk created from the [debian-7-wheezy-v20130617](https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta15/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20130617) image with data, which I am trying to access.

I came up with 2 possible solutions to access the data:

1. Create a new VM with the old bootdisk. Sounds easy, but Google changed something and the VM won't boot.
2. Create a new VM with a new image and attach the old bootdisk. Sounds easy, but the old disk is not recognized using good old `safe_format_and_mount`.

Any ideas how to access the data from the disk? The [migration doc](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/transition-v1) didn't really help, it seems they assume you always have the old VM with the old disk still running.

Comment: There is no automatic "migration" between Zones, you have to do this yourself (or automate it) between scheduled outage windows (which are shown/updated many months before in the Zones section of the cloud console). The __On host maintenance__ setting under __Availability policy__ it set to __Migrate VM instance__ by default, however as it says, this only applies when the host machine undergoes maintenance that may temporarily affect instance performance.

Answer (score 1):

As your disks were created before the migration to the current v1 API, before you can re-attach the disk to a new instance, you must [upgrade the disk](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/transition-v1#upgradepd) to use an embedded kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to access the data on old disks in a new VM.

1. Create a new VM with a current OS image.
2. In addition attach old boot disks as read only
3. In the VM check attached disks with `ls -la /dev/sd*` . "sda" is boot, the others attached.

> brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  0 Jan 22 11:18 /dev/sda
>   brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  1 Jan 22 11:18 /dev/sda1
>   brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 16 Jan 22 11:18 /dev/sdb
>   brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 17 Jan 22 11:18 /dev/sdb1
>   brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 32 Jan 22 11:49 /dev/sdc
>   brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 33 Jan 22 11:49 /dev/sdc1

4 Create mount point `mkdir /mnt/disk_b` and mount disk partition `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disk_b`.

> mount: block device /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only

5 Check your data `ls -la /mnt/disk_b`

Comment: You should probably be root on the VM: `sudo bash`