# Is there any way to manually migrate a GCE VM in a maintenance window?

Tags: google-compute-engine

With no warning e-mail, it seems that europe-west1 Zone B has gone down for maintenance, for 16 days until the 1st April 2014. Being that GCE is a cloud based service and that I have the automatic 'migrate on maintenance' setting enabled, I assumed that I had nothing to worry about. However, after the VM was terminated last night and I reread 'Designing Robust Systems' it seems that I was badly mistaken/misled! It will take 3 days work to rebuild a new server and I have 20 students with data locked up for two weeks in the middle of the semester. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281948/how-to-migrate-old-google-compute-engine-disks

Comment: IanGSY, under 'Availability policies' I have "On host maintenance: Migrate VM" enabled. I saw your answer to a similar question saying that this does *not* in fact happen, but it is also stated that all resources for a zone in maintenance are inaccessible (i.e. the root persistent disk)!? Surely, there must be other people who are in (or have been in) a similar situation (perhaps in January) who have managed to get the issue resolved somehow?

Comment: After further investigation, it seems that if you are a European GCE customer "On host maintenance: Migrate VM" is a profoundly misleading option (or pretty much a lie), because it only works in the 'transparent' US zones! Furthermore, if you are a European GCE customer unlucky enough to get caught out by this, tough luck! Your instance and persistent disk are completely inaccessible for the entire 16 day maintenance window period, you can't even take a snapshot. Well done, big G! You've succeeded in doing quite a lot of harm, to quite a number of people!

Answer (score 2):

I made the exact same mistake. I have been in contact with Google, and there is NOTHING we can do but wait for the maintenace window to exit.

Also, my instance is now removed, so I will have to re-create the instance and attach to my persistent disk.